# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure AND BeanEntityManager error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Have had to cut the first error message quite abit since it contained to many characters, but the full thing can be found here: https://github.com/kableiv/FullSpringError

Bit of backstory:
Completing an assignment and need to create a small website where 2 predefined users can login, one with user privileges and one with admin, the privileges are buttons that redirect you to pages where you edit, delete and register new info. At first I did it without spring security and no database, using arraylists and files. When I logged in with the user it only had the user privileges like it was supposed to, however when I logged in with the admin and then went onto any of the other html pages like the one used to edit something and then clicked on the return button, the admin privileges were gone. Im assuming this was because i, in my method to login, sat its admin value to true(so the html page knew what to display and what not to) and then when that method was done and a new one was starting like the editing method the value was back to null.

Because of this I decided to try and switch to using a MySQL database with spring security.
My IDE of choice is intellij ultimate and I used MySQL Workbench to setup the database and added it into intellij using the database feature.

Now when trying to run the project i get the following error:

```
2018-05-04 16:59:10.780  INFO 8364 --- [           main] com.rfboernehave.demo.DemoApplication    : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-QB8IIQF with PID 8364 (C:\Users\nerdi\SpringbootWebAppMiniproject1\target\classes started by nerdi in C:\Users\nerdi\SpringbootWebAppMiniproject1)
2018-05-04 16:59:10.783  INFO 8364 --- [           main] com.rfboernehave.demo.DemoApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-05-04 16:59:11.390  INFO 8364 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@516be40f: startup date [Fri May 04 16:59:11 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-04 16:59:14.723  INFO 8364 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
2018-05-04 16:59:14.747  INFO 8364 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-05-04 16:59:14.747  INFO 8364 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2018-05-04 16:59:15.021  INFO 8364 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-05-04 16:59:15.021  INFO 8364 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3638 ms
2018-05-04 16:59:15.343  INFO 8364 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-04 16:59:15.343  INFO 8364 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-04 16:59:15.343  INFO 8364 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-04 16:59:15.343  INFO 8364 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-04 16:59:15.343  INFO 8364 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-05-04 16:59:15.347  INFO 8364 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-05-04 16:59:18.235 ERROR 8364 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2196) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2229) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2024) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]

at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366) [spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4aac97b.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$5(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4aac97b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6844864e.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]



org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.rfboernehave.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]


Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

NOW I have tried adding hibernating dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Which gave me this other error instead:

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2018-05-04 16:36:20.358  INFO 19272 --- [           main] com.rfboernehave.demo.DemoApplication    : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-QB8IIQF with PID 19272 (C:\Users\nerdi\SpringbootWebAppMiniproject1\target\classes started by nerdi in C:\Users\nerdi\SpringbootWebAppMiniproject1)
2018-05-04 16:36:20.358  INFO 19272 --- [           main] com.rfboernehave.demo.DemoApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-05-04 16:36:21.064  INFO 19272 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@77be656f: startup date [Fri May 04 16:36:21 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-04 16:36:23.488  INFO 19272 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
2018-05-04 16:36:23.501  INFO 19272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-05-04 16:36:23.501  INFO 19272 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2018-05-04 16:36:23.722  INFO 19272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-05-04 16:36:23.722  INFO 19272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2658 ms
2018-05-04 16:36:23.935  INFO 19272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-04 16:36:23.935  INFO 19272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-04 16:36:23.935  INFO 19272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-04 16:36:23.935  INFO 19272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-04 16:36:23.938  INFO 19272 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-05-04 16:36:23.939  INFO 19272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-05-04 16:36:24.010  WARN 19272 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file [C:\Users\nerdi\SpringbootWebAppMiniproject1\target\classes\com\rfboernehave\demo\controller\HomeController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'brugerServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\nerdi\SpringbootWebAppMiniproject1\target\classes\com\rfboernehave\demo\services\BrugerServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brugerRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#703feacd' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#703feacd': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2018-05-04 16:36:24.012  INFO 19272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-05-04 16:36:24.036  INFO 19272 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-04 16:36:24.114 ERROR 19272 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.rfboernehave.demo.services.BrugerServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

NOW I also got rid of this thing(not sure if did it correctly though) but it gave me a similair error but asking me to define a bean of type package. I decided to remove the dependencies and are therefore currently sitting with the first error of the post.

Below is my current pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.rfboernhave</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.springframework.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
            <version>27</version>
        </dependency>





        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

My application.properties:

```
server.port=5000
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:5000/test_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

My Config.java class:

```
package com.rfboernehave.demo.Security;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;



    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password from user where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, rolle from user where username=?");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login*").anonymous()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")

            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }

}
```

My entity(MyUser) class : I apologize for the variables being in a foreign language quick translation:
MinBruger is (MyUser)
brugernavn is (username)
adgangskode is (password)
rolle is (role)

```
package com.rfboernehave.demo.domains;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MinBruger {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String brugernavn;
    private String adgangskode;
    private String rolle;
    private int id;

    public MinBruger() {
    }

    public MinBruger(int id, String brugernavn, String adgangskode, String rolle) {
        this.id = id;
        this.brugernavn = brugernavn;
        this.adgangskode = adgangskode;
        this.rolle = rolle;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrugernavn() {
        return brugernavn;
    }

    public void setBrugernavn(String brugernavn) {
        this.brugernavn = brugernavn;
    }

    public String getAdgangskode() {
        return adgangskode;
    }

    public void setAdgangskode(String adgangskode) {
        this.adgangskode = adgangskode;
    }

    public String getRolle(){return rolle;}

    public void setRolle(String rolle) {
        this.rolle = rolle;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MinBruger{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", brugernavn='" + brugernavn + '\'' +
                ", adgangskode='" + adgangskode + '\'' +
                ", rolle=" + rolle + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

Below is my UserRepository:
Translation:
BrugerRepository is (UserRepository)

```
package com.rfboernehave.demo.repositories;

import com.rfboernehave.demo.domains.MinBruger;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface BrugerRepository extends CrudRepository<MinBruger, String> {

}
```

How can I fix this?
Thx in Advance.

Comment: based on the latest exception message, I would try to set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` property...also 'd check the db *version* (!)/connectivity/url+credentials

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Ok so I sat the property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Aside from that I also changed the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
```

TO:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db?useSSL=false
```

This seemed to do part of the trick, my project now runs, however a new problem arisen, when trying to login it fails and sets the url from: http://localhost:5000/login

TO: http://localhost:5000/login?error

Below is my HomeController.java:

```
        package com.rfboernehave.demo.controller;

import com.rfboernehave.demo.domains.Barn;
import com.rfboernehave.demo.domains.MinBruger;
import com.rfboernehave.demo.services.BarnServiceImpl;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Controller
public class HomeController {


    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());


    @Autowired

    private BarnServiceImpl barnService;


    public HomeController() {
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/", "index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        log.info("index method called...");


        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        log.info("login method called with: ");

        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("admin"))) {
            return "redirect:/home";
        }

        return "login";
    }
//
//
   @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {
       log.info("home action called...");

       model.addAttribute("boern", barnService.hentAlleBoern());

       log.info("home action ended...");
       return "home";
   }


    @GetMapping("/registrer")
    public String registrer(Model model) {
        log.info("registrer action called...");
        model.addAttribute("barn", new Barn());
        return "registrer";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registrer")
    public String registrer(@ModelAttribute Barn barn, Model model) throws FileNotFoundException {
        log.info("registrer post action called...");
        String home = Integer.toString(barnService.hentAlleBoern().size());
        barn.setId(Integer.parseInt(home));
        barnService.hentAlleBoern().add(barn);
        barnService.printToFile();
        model.addAttribute("boern", barnService.hentAlleBoern());
        return "/home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/detaljer/{id}")
    public String detaljer(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        log.info("detaljer action called...");


        Barn lille = null;


        for (Barn barn : barnService.hentAlleBoern()) {
            if (barn.getId() == id) {
                lille = barn;
                break;
            }
        }

        model.addAttribute("barn", lille);
        model.addAttribute("boern", barnService.hentAlleBoern());



        return "detaljer";
    }

    @GetMapping("/afmeld/{id}")
    public String afmeld(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        log.info("afmeld  action called...");
        model.addAttribute("barn",barnService.hentAlleBoern().get(id));
        model.addAttribute("boern", barnService.hentAlleBoern());
        return "afmeld";
    }

    @PostMapping("/afmeld")
    public String afmeld(@ModelAttribute Barn barn, Model model) throws FileNotFoundException {
        log.info("afmeld post action called...");
        int id = barn.getId();
        barnService.hentAlleBoern().remove(barn.getId());

        leftShiftId(barnService.hentAlleBoern(), id);
        barnService.printToFile();
        model.addAttribute("boern", barnService.hentAlleBoern());
        return "/home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/rediger/{id}")
    public String rediger(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        log.info("rediger action called...");


        model.addAttribute("barn", barnService.hentAlleBoern().get(id));
        model.addAttribute("boern", barnService.hentAlleBoern());
        return "rediger";
    }

    @PostMapping("/rediger")
    public String rediger(@ModelAttribute Barn barn, Model model) throws FileNotFoundException {
        log.info("rediger post action called...");
        for (int i = 0; i < barnService.hentAlleBoern().size(); i++) {
            if (barn.getId() == barnService.hentAlleBoern().get(i).getId()) {
                barnService.hentAlleBoern().set(i, barn);

                break;
            }
        }
        barnService.printToFile();
        model.addAttribute("boern", barnService.hentAlleBoern());
        return "/home";
    }

    private void leftShiftId(ArrayList<Barn> list, int id) {
        log.info("leftshift method called...");
        for (int i = id; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Barn barn = list.get(i);
            barn.setId(barn.getId() - 1);
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the terminal output:

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2018-05-08 13:18:32.979  INFO 1872 --- [           main] com.rfboernehave.demo.DemoApplication    : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-QB8IIQF with PID 1872 (C:\Users\nerdi\SpringbootWebAppMiniproject1\target\classes started by nerdi in C:\Users\nerdi\SpringbootWebAppMiniproject1)
2018-05-08 13:18:32.982  INFO 1872 --- [           main] com.rfboernehave.demo.DemoApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-05-08 13:18:33.671  INFO 1872 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@516be40f: startup date [Tue May 08 13:18:33 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-08 13:18:36.652  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
2018-05-08 13:18:36.666  INFO 1872 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-05-08 13:18:36.667  INFO 1872 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2018-05-08 13:18:36.878  INFO 1872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-05-08 13:18:36.878  INFO 1872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3210 ms
2018-05-08 13:18:37.170  INFO 1872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-08 13:18:37.170  INFO 1872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-08 13:18:37.170  INFO 1872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-08 13:18:37.170  INFO 1872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-05-08 13:18:37.172  INFO 1872 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-05-08 13:18:37.172  INFO 1872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-05-08 13:18:37.907  INFO 1872 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-05-08 13:18:37.929  INFO 1872 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-05-08 13:18:38.204  INFO 1872 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2018-05-08 13:18:38.205  INFO 1872 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-05-08 13:18:38.207  INFO 1872 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-05-08 13:18:38.256  INFO 1872 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-05-08 13:18:38.425  INFO 1872 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2018-05-08 13:18:39.001  INFO 1872 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-05-08 13:18:39.571  INFO 1872 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@11b5f4e2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@33e0c716, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@634ca3e7, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6ee88e21, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@d653e41, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@17222c11, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6274f21c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@12952aff, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6bcae9, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@b14b60a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@50b734c4, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@67688110]
2018-05-08 13:18:40.196  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@516be40f: startup date [Tue May 08 13:18:33 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-08 13:18:40.337  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[ || / || /index],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.rfboernehave.demo.controller.HomeController.index()
2018-05-08 13:18:40.338  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/home],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.rfboernehave.demo.controller.HomeController.home(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-05-08 13:18:40.339  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/rediger],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.rfboernehave.demo.controller.HomeController.rediger(com.rfboernehave.demo.domains.Barn,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
2018-05-08 13:18:40.339  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/rediger/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.rfboernehave.demo.controller.HomeController.rediger(int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-05-08 13:18:40.340  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/detaljer/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.rfboernehave.demo.controller.HomeController.detaljer(int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-05-08 13:18:40.341  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.rfboernehave.demo.controller.HomeController.login()
2018-05-08 13:18:40.342  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/registrer],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.rfboernehave.demo.controller.HomeController.registrer(com.rfboernehave.demo.domains.Barn,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
2018-05-08 13:18:40.342  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/registrer],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.rfboernehave.demo.controller.HomeController.registrer(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-05-08 13:18:40.343  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/afmeld],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.rfboernehave.demo.controller.HomeController.afmeld(com.rfboernehave.demo.domains.Barn,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
2018-05-08 13:18:40.344  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/afmeld/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.rfboernehave.demo.controller.HomeController.afmeld(int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-05-08 13:18:40.347  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-05-08 13:18:40.348  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-05-08 13:18:40.398  INFO 1872 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-08 13:18:40.400  INFO 1872 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-08 13:18:40.477  INFO 1872 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-08 13:18:41.111  INFO 1872 --- [           main] b.a.s.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration : 

Using default security password: 4f2b3afb-8328-4fa1-a16c-e16003f15618

2018-05-08 13:18:41.294  INFO 1872 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-05-08 13:18:41.396  INFO 1872 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http)
2018-05-08 13:18:41.403  INFO 1872 --- [           main] com.rfboernehave.demo.DemoApplication    : Started DemoApplication in 8.91 seconds (JVM running for 9.612)
```